# A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:doc-available() xslt 2 3

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have an XML document that is a list of XML documents:

dmIndex.xml:

```
<dmIndex>
    <dmFile href="DME-SF518-CCC-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-00_en-US.XML"
            dmIndex="S1000D-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-A"/>
   <dmFile href="DME-SF518-MMM-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-00_en-US.XML"
            dmIndex="S1000D-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-A"/>
   <dmFile href="SAMPLE-A-05-21-0010-00AAA-913A-A_EN-US.xml"
            dmIndex="SAMPLE-A-05-21-0010-00AAA-913A-A"/>
   <dmFile href="UPF-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-00_en-US.XML"
            dmIndex=""/>
   <dmFile href="SAMPLE-A-55-10-0000-00AAA-140A-A_EN-US.xml"
            dmIndex="SAMPLE-A-55-10-0000-00AAA-140A-A"/>
   <dmFile href="SAMPLE-A-95-10-0000-00AAA-140A-A_EN-US.xml"
            dmIndex="SAMPLE-A-95-10-0000-00AAA-140A-A"/>
   <dmFile href="descript_sample.xml" dmIndex="00-0-00-00-00-000-0000-A"/>
   <dmFile href="proced_sample_dmRef_Checkout.xml"
            dmIndex="SAMPLE-A-05-10-0000-00AAA-913A-A"/>
   <dmFile href="DMC-FJ-A-00-00-00-00A-003A-A.xml"
            dmIndex="FJ-A-00-00-00-00A-003A-A"/>
</dmIndex>
```

xslt:

```
<xsl:param name="dmIndex" select="'dmIndex.xml'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="dmRefFile" select="document($dmIndex)//dmFile[@dmIndex='S1000D-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-A']/@href"/>
  <xsl:if test="doc-available($dmRefFile)">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document($dmRefFile)/dmodule"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'd like to test if the document exists before processing, but I'm getting the error: *A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:doc-available()*

`@dmIndex` is not unique and can be empty, but I don't know how to filter the `select` statement correctly to return one `@href`. I've tried `[1]` in different places:

```
document($dmIndex)//dmFile[@dmIndex='S1000D-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-A']/@href[1]
document($dmIndex)//dmFile[@dmIndex='S1000D-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-A'][1]/@href
doc-available($dmRefFile[1])
```

I'm open to a better way of testing `dmRefFile`, it would only be for XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc($dmIndex)//dmFile[@dmIndex='S1000D-AAA-D00-00-00-00AA-131A-A']/@href[doc-available(.)]/doc(.)/dmodule"/>`

Comment: Thank you, Martin. This eliminates the `dmRefFile` variable and `xsl:if` statement? This expression is used in many templates with different variations, does the `[doc-available(.)]` predicate filter to one `@href` or do I need the entire expression for it to make sense?

Comment: The suggested single `xsl:apply-templates` is indeed meant as a replacement for the whole contents of the template you showed. As for your second question, if you write `@href[doc-available(.)]`, then that predicate, like any, is applied to each node on the left e.g. to each `@href` attribute selected on the left. That is about the only way the use of `doc-available` makes sense, to apply it to a single URL.

Comment: I thought I could store the predicate in a variable `<xsl:variable name="dmRefFile" select="doc($dmIndex)//dmFile[@dmIndex=$DMC]/@href[doc-available(.)]"/>`  so I could apply it elsewhere. But I'm getting the same sequence error when I test the variable with `doc-available($dmRefFile)`. I just want to know if setting the variable is valid, I could have made a mistake somewhere else. I'm also getting the sequence error when I do `<xsl:apply-templates select="doc($dmRefFile)/dmodule"`

Comment: Use `select="$dmRefFile/doc(.)/dmodule"`.

Comment: I tried this after re-reading your comment "then that predicate, like any, is applied to each node on the left e.g. to each @href attribute selected on the left." The light bulb finally went on. Thank you, this has been so helpful for me, Martin.